# I'm not sure how to run this macro properly

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to take existing word files that were created with smart quotes, I have to open each document and replace the quotes, then save and close. I wrote the macro, that works perfectly using the recorder function on word.

Now I've seen people write macros that can run the macro in a loop on each file in the folder but I have no idea where I actually run that macro from.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    ActiveDocument.Convert
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = """"
        .Replacement.Text = """"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "'"
        .Replacement.Text = "'"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory _
        "\\EXPRESS-SERVER\MTMQuote\Quote Archive\Quote Archive (Out Dated)\Expert Quotes\120001-130000 (2013-)\125001-126000 (2015)\Updated\"
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:= _
        (ActiveDocument.Name) _
        , FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault, LockComments:=False, Password:="", _
        AddToRecentFiles:=True, WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
        EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData _
        :=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, CompatibilityMode:=15
    ActiveDocument.Close
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

How do I run this over and over? there are about 1000 files in the folder on my desktop called "MTMUPDATES"

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

(but don't name them all the same thing, make whatever you use to name the docs count up or something)

```vb
Sub replacer()
   Dim MyDialog As FileDialog, GetStr(1 To 1000) As String '1000 files is the maximum applying this code

   On Error Resume Next

   Set MyDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
   With MyDialog
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "All WORD File ", "*.*", 1
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
      i = 1
      If .Show = -1 Then
         For Each stiSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
           GetStr(i) = stiSelectedItem
           i = i + 1
         Next
         i = i - 1
      End If

      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      For j = 1 To i Step 1
        Set Doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=GetStr(j), Visible:=True)
        Windows(GetStr(j)).Activate
        Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

        With Selection.Find
         .Text = "'" 'find what
         .Replacement.Text = "'" 'replace with
         .Forward = True
         .Wrap = wdFindAsk
         .Format = False
         .MatchCase = False
         .MatchWholeWord = False
         .MatchByte = True
         .MatchWildcards = False
         .MatchSoundsLike = False
         .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Application.Run macroname:="NEWMACROS"

        docname = InputBox("Enter file name", "docname") 'replace this with some sort of naming device or use the next thing
        newname = docname & ".doc"
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=newname

        'ActiveDocument.Save 'use this if you just want to save the document. remove the apostrophe before and delete the previous little expression or put apostrophes in front of it

        ActiveWindow.Close
      Next
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   End With
   MsgBox "operation end, please view", vbInformation

End Sub
```